# SQL Server - Update Statistics FULL scan vs Auto Update

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization

Something I have been trying to figure out..

I take a table with 2 billion + rows and I run a manual stats update with `FULLSCAN`

Sometime in the future, an automatic update stats runs against the table, does this automatic stats update *overwrite* the collection done by the `FULLSCAN` update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what will happen. The default sample percentage will be used, unless you update the statistics with `PERSIST_SAMPLE_PERCENT = ON`

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#persist_sample_percent---on--off-):

> If AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS is executed, it uses the persisted sampling
> percentage if available, or use default sampling percentage if not.